# Selecting randomly from a list with a specific character

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have a text file (full of words) I put into a list. I want Python 2.7 to select a word from the list randomly, but for it to start in a specific character.

list code:

```
d=[]

with open("dic.txt", "r") as x:
    d=[line.strip() for line in x]
```

It's for a game called Shiritori. The user starts with saying any word in the English language, ie dog. The program then has to pick another word starting with the last character, in this case, 'g'.

code for the game:

```
game_user='-1'

game_user=raw_input("em, lets go with ")

a1=len(game_user)
```

I need a program that will randomly select a word beginning with that character.

Comment: Where's your code? What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Because your game relies specifically upon a random word with a fixed starting letter, I suggest first sorting all your words into a dictionary with the starting letter as the key. Then, you can randomly lookup any word starting with a given letter:

```
d=[]
lookup = {}

with open("dic.txt", "r") as x:
    d=[line.strip() for line in x]

for word in d:
   if word[0] in lookup:
      lookup[word[0]].append(word)
   else:
      lookup[word[0]] = [ word ]
```

now you have a `dict` 'lookup' that has all your words sorted by letter.
When you need a word that starts with the last letter of the previous word, you can randomly pick an element in your list:

```
import random
random_word = random.choice(lookup[ game_user[-1] ])
```

Comment: +1 for this being only limited to access time of a dictionary rather than needing to generate a new list every time a new round is played

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a new list of all the values that start with the last letter of the user input:

```
choices = [x in d if x[0] == game_user[-1]]
```

Then, you can select a word by:

```
newWord = random.choice(choices)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use enumerate, if you want to get words and not indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import random
>>> with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
...     words = f.read().splitlines()
...
>>> c = 'a'
>>> random.choice([w for w in words if w.startswith(c)])
'anthologizing'
```

Obviously, you need to replace `c = 'a'` with `raw_input("em, lets go with ")`

Answer (score 0):

You might get better use out of more advanced data structures, but here's a shot:

```
words_dict = {}
for row in d:
    # Gives us the first letter
    myletter = row[0]
    if myletter not in words_dict:
        words_dict[myletter] = []
    words_dict[myletter].append(row)
```

After creating a dictionary of all letters and their corresponding words, you can then access any particular set of words like so:

```
words_dict['a']
```

Which will give you all the words that start with a in a list. Then you can take:

```
# This could be any letter here..
someletter = 'a'
newword = words_dict[someletter][random.randint(0,len(words_dict[someletter]-1))]
```

Let me know if that makes sense?